# How to NOT trigger mouseleave on parent when mouseenter on child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

Haven't been able to get this work.  Without going to my exact situation and why I'm trying to do what I'm doing, a basic abstract is:

I have 4 elements child elements inside a parent .  I currently am attaching a `mouseenter` to the children so:

```
$('.parent').on('mouseenter', '.child', function() {
    showSomething();
});
```

Then I'm trying to say

```
$('.parent').on('mouseleave', function() {
    hideSameSomething();
});
```

But when the `mouseenter` on the child fires a `mouseleave` on the parent and creates a nasty flicker.  I've tried `e.stopPropagation()` on the child handler but no luck.  Any ideas how to not fire the parent `mouseleave` event when I'm entering the child elements and only when I really leave the parent?

Answer (score 2):

Try combining both into one.

**Official Document** : http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data

```
$(".parent, .child").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // Handle mouseenter...
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // Handle mouseleave...
    }
});
```

Comment: That's binding the events to only child.  I want the events to be handle separately by not having anything fired by the parent when I mouseenter the child, just when I literally mouseleave the parent.

Comment: I think he want to say : `$(".parent, .child")`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.parent .child').on("mouseenter", function() {

    showSomething();

    $(this).closest('.parent').on("mouseleave", function() {
        hideSameSomething();
    });

});
```